# How to parse Typescript Definition files programmatically?

Tags: typescript

Is there a parser for Typescript definition files (*.d.ts)? For a give declared class, I would like to retrieve the name of each function and the name/type of their parameters. I would also like to retrieve the documentation for each function and its parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse typescript definition to json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588436/how-to-parse-typescript-definition-to-json)

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful for you: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API